# Align Grid nicely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, material-ui

I'm breaking my head over this. I'm using a Grid container, which contains two grids. One with a textfield , and one with a Checkbox . The grids refuses to align correctly.

```
   <Grid container>
    <Grid item sm={2}>
     <TextField
      id="filter"
      label={labels.filterHelperText}
      value={this.props.brokersListFilter}
      onChange={this.onFilterChange}
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <FilterListIcon />
          </InputAdornment>
        )
      }}
    />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item sm={1}>
        <FormControlLabel
          className={this.props.classes.checkbox}
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={this.props.activeAgentsOnly}
              onChange={this.props.setActiveAgentsOnly}
              color="primary"
            />
          }
          label={labels.isActive}
        />
      </Grid>
     </Grid>
```

With this code, the spacing are too large... If I change the first inner grid to `sm={1}` , then both grid overlap each other(how is it even possible if they're on different grids ?) I need to somehow make the gap between those two grids smaller .. How can I do that?

Over lapping:
[image]

Not over lapping:
[image]

Comment: What grid system are you using? and can you provide an image of the overlapping?

Comment: @Chris Material-ui grid. I've uploaded an image

Comment: please add you css style component of jss

Answer (score 0):

Please update grid items like

```
<Grid item sm={2}>
```

to

```
<Grid item sm={6}>
<Grid item sm={6}>
```

Should equal 12. 8+4 or 6+6 or so on.....

Comment: It wasn't that, I was simply missing `fullWidth` attribute :D